# ajax call wont show json data from restcall

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

Im trying to use ajax to display json from a get rest call i make, but it wont show anything

jsp ajax code:

```
function myFunction() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/app_kiem/api/huisservice/getlist',
        dataType: 'json',
    }).then(function(data) {
        $('.demo').append(data.value);
        console.log("what.jpg")
    });
}
```

i use the function here:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="span-24">
        <h2>Houses</h2>
        <p class="demo">The ID is</p>
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

if i make the restcall in postman i get this output:
[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eIWx.png)

Comment: If your response is like `{"value":"901"}` not an array then `console.log(data.value)` would be fine.If an array then you should iterate over the array after json parse.

Comment: yes thank you, i realised now that if i change dataType to text it should also work

Comment: You do not need to change the data type. You can do `JSON.stringify(data)`;